# Jssor - Changing container background color when image changes

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

I am using Jssor image slider and its working perfectly. My question is, is there a way to change the background color of the container as the image changes? Is there any attribute that needs to be added to the option section in the JS?

Any info related to this matter will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should 1) post code 2) post a link if you're using something pre-built and 3) create a jsfiddle.net version if possible. This will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get it work.

a. Manually set background color for each slide

```
    <div style="background-color: green;"><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue;"><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
```

b. Place jssor slider in a container, and then change background-color when slide changed.

```
        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, function (slideIndex, fromeIndex) {
            if (slideIndex == 0) {
                //change container background color to green
            }
            else if (slideIndex == 1) {
                //change container background color to blue
            }
        });
```